# unique_ptr - invalid pointer and segfault

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, sfml, unique-ptr

I am learning a new C++11 standard and writing small game in SFML. I have followed code where I am trying to pass a pointer of a sprite to another object.

```
bool Game::detectCollision()
{
    std::unique_ptr<sf::Sprite> sprPtr1(&iPlayer.charSprite);
    return field.detectCollision(sprPtr1);
}

bool FieldElem::detectCollision(std::unique_ptr<sf::Sprite> charSprite)
{
    std::cout << "X: " << charSprite->getPosition().x << std::endl;
    return true;
}
```

This code compiles without warning and gives me following segfault during a runtime:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./game: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fffb8617d90 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7eb96)[0x7f8694b37b96]
./game(_ZN2sf6SpriteD0Ev+0x24)[0x405772]
```

Why my pointer is invalid? I think I am missing some important detail regarding unique_ptr...

Comment: Was `charSprite` allocated using `new`?

Comment: Your code shouldn't even compile, as `std::unique_ptr` isn't copyable, only moveable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr` assumes sole ownership of the pointed-to object, and deletes the object when the `unique_ptr` goes out of scope. So after `detectCollision` returns, `charSprite` is deleted. Since you never actually allocated `charSprite` (but rather allocated `iPlayer`, with `charSprite` in it), that's not kosher.

It sounds like you don't actually want `unique_ptr` here. You don't intend to transfer ownership.

Comment: Yes, right - thanks for pointing this out. So in this case it was destroyed because of the going out of the scope. However when I was trying to use shared_ptr - I was getting segfault as well - why?. It works with regular pointer...

Comment: You probably don't want `shared_ptr` either. It's a one-line function, with no retained ownership. What's wrong with regular pointers?

Comment: What I wanted to achieve is to trying to understand limitations (why it segfaults) with smart pointers.

Comment: It segfaults because smart pointers are intended to manage ownership, to delete things at the appropriate time. The appropriate time, in this instance, is 'never'.